# Does sizeof returns the amount of memory allocated?

Tags: c, memory, types, sizeof

I read that:

> sizeof operator returns the size of the data type, not the amount of memory allocated to the variable.

Isn't the amount of *memory allocated* depends on the size of the data type? I mean that `sizeof` will return 4 (*architecture-dependent*) when I pass `int` to it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: After `int *foo = malloc(1000);` the allocated memory is **not** returned by `sizeof` --- `sizeof foo == sizeof (int*)` and `sizeof *foo == sizeof (int)`. Also note the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of an `int` (as it appears to be in your implementation).

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: @Niraj Raut The memory allocated for an object is defined by its type.

Comment: The statement you quote was probably made in the context of using `malloc`, where after `char *x = malloc(n)`, the expression `sizeof(x)` will not return `n`. But of course `sizeof(x)` bytes are allocated to store the pointer itself.

Comment: @pmg Your example does not make sense and has nothing common with the sizeof operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you quote is technically incorrect. `sizeof variable_name` does return the size of memory that the variable called `variable_name` occupies.

The text makes a common mistake of conflating a pointer with the memory it points to. Those are two separate things. If a pointer points to an allocated block, then that block is not allocated to the pointer. (Nor are the contents of the block stored in the pointer -- another common mistake).

The allocation exists in its own right, the pointer variable exists elsewhere, and the pointer variable points to the allocation. The pointer variable could be changed to point elsewhere without disturbing the allocation.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Now, this is not related to the question but please answer. Why is ```char *argv[]``` and ```char **argv``` the same thing in the case of function parameters?

Comment: @NirajRaut you should not ask new questions in comments . If you search this site for those terms you should find the answer

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns the number of bytes that a variable or stack allocated array occupies.

Examples:

- `sizeof(char)=1` (in most configurations)
- But `sizeof(char*)=8` (depending on the platform)
- If you dynamically allocate memory with `malloc`, you will receive a pointer to that block of memory. If use the `sizeof` on it, you will just get the size of the pointer.
- However, `sizeof()` a stack allocated array like when you write `int a[10]` is the size of the allocated memory (so 4*10)

The size of the pointer doesn't depend on the size of the datatype it represents. (On 32 bit platforms, a pointer is 32bit)

Comment: `in most configurations` C standard mandates that `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: "*`sizeof(char)` shall always be 1.*"

Comment: "The size of the pointer doesn't depend on the size of the datatype it represents." --> Not quite.  Within restrictions, the size of a pointer can vary with type.  Fairly common that a pointer to a function has a different size than a `void *`.

Comment: "On 32 bit platforms, a pointer is 32bit" --> the 32-is  often the size of the native `int/unsigned`, not the common pointer.  There is a tendency that the pointer width tracks the processor `n`, yet C does not specify it and various exceptions have/do occur.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof returns the number of bytes

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

but the size of each byte is not guaranteed to be 8. So you don't obtain directly the amount of memory allocated.

> A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined

anyway you can deduce the amount of memory allocated using the CHAR_BIT constant, which contains the number of bit is a byte.

Comment: `the size of each byte is not guaranteed to be 8. So you cannot deduce the amount of memory allocated.` Well, just `sizeof(the_thing) * CHAR_BITS` if you want to have the count of bits in `the_thing` then.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that, I will correct the answer accordingly

Answer (score -1):

"*Memory allocation*" in C typically refers to explicit allocation (i.e: on the heap - `malloc()` and friends), or implicit allocation (i.e: on the stack).

As you've defined, `sizeof()` returns the size of the data type:

- `sizeof(char)` - a single `char`
- `sizeof(void *)` - an `void` pointer

If you call `malloc(sizeof(int))`, you're requesting "*enough memory to hold the data for an `int`*", which may be 4 bytes on your system... you may find that more memory than you requested is allocated (though this will typically be hidden from you, see [canaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection)).

Additionally, if you call `int *x = malloc(1024)`, and `sizeof(*x)`, you might get `4`, because an `int` happens to be 4 bytes... even though the memory you've allocated is 1 KiB. If you were to incorrectly call `sizeof(x)`, then you'll get the size of a pointer returned, not the size of the type it points to. Neither of these (`sizeof(*x)` or `sizeof(x)`) will return `1024`.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear why my answer is wrong, but I also don't want to fight about it...

Comment: In this declaration int *x = malloc(1024) the dynamically allocated memory has nothing common with any object. Each object is defined by its type.